# PS1 prompt showing different on local and remote console

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, prompt, window-title

This is my PS1 prompt:

```
export PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "
```

That shows **perfect in remote** (SSH) console (PTS):

```
luis@Chomsky:~$
```

Can not show it, but the full prompt is in violet color.
The problem is: in **local (TTY)**, it shows some ugly:

```
;luis@Chomsky: ~luis@Chomsky:~$
```

Can not show it neither, but the first part (from ";" to "~") has no color, and the rest is in violet color.

```
Additional data:
```

- Using Bash Shell:

`luis@Chomsky:~$ ps -p$$ -ocmd=
-bash`

- Tested in Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server v14.04 LTS.
- Tested (at least) in a portable ASUS EEE PC and on VirtualBox virtual machine.
- I use to add the `export PS1=` line at `~/.bashrc`.

I would like to know why is this happening and how could I **solve it**.

Thanks.

Comment: What shell are you using? Are both machines using the same one? How/where are you setting `PS1`?

Comment: @terdon, added the requested info to the original post.

Comment: Are you doing anything to `PS1` in `~/.profile`?

Comment: @terdon, the command `cat ~/.profile | grep "ps1" -i` shows no results, so I think not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control sequence `\e]0;TITLE\a` is recognized by many terminal emulators; it sets the window title. This control sequence is not recognized by the Linux console (which doesn't have a title anyway): it sees `\e]0`, decides “I don't know what this means, so I'll ignore it”, and prints the following text.

You'll need to set your prompt differently depending on the current terminal.

```
title_text='\u@\h: \w'
set_title=
case $TERM in
  dtterm|rxvt|[Ek]term|*xterm) set_title='\[\e]0;'"$title_text"'\a\]';;
  screen) set_title='\[\ek'"$title_text"'\e\\\]';;
esac
PS1="$set_title$PS1"
```

Comment: Well, it is rather complicated, but I have pasted it to a `.sh` script, executed, and nothing seems to have changed. At least my prompt keeps the same.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Did you run this in a separate script? That won't work: the script doesn't influence its parent shell. You need to run this inside bash. This code is meant to go into your `.bashrc`. Since I add the title-setting code to what's already there, this should replace the existing part that adds the title-setting code.

Comment: Tested in both ways. Even on `~/.bashrc` nothing seems to have changed. I put your script right after my `export PS1=` line.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Put `set -x` before the snippet and `set +x` after, and tell me what is printed when you run bash (it'll start with `+ title_text='\u@\h: \w'`) as well as the resulting value of `PS1` (edit your question or use http://pastebin.com/ or whatever you prefer).

Comment: Here you have, thanks you: http://pastebin.com/ish0Epnu

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Remove your old `export PS1=…` line.

Comment: But if I remove my `export PS1=...` line the prompt will not be my desired prompt. Where will I specify the value of my PS1 variable, then?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Isn't your prompt the title-setting bit followed by the default bit? Anyway, if you prefer to set `PS1`, then don't set the title-setting bit, since my snippet adds it. Change it to `PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "`

Comment: All right, I understand now: it was a matter of title-setting. In the cases of X-Windows the terminals will have a modified window title, but not in cases of text console. Your script, in fact, solves both cases and I can keep my PS1 config by removing the title setting bits. You should add it to your answer to make things clearer. Thanks again.